# Utils.CopyArray in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

[`Utils.CopyArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.utils.copyarray.aspx) is a method in Visual Basic.net but what's its replicate in C#?
I tried looking at msdn but no clue.

Comment: I don't know the exact semantics of `Utils.CopyArray`, but [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) is probably similar.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx

Comment: This is a "real question."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily reference the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, including the `Utils` class, from C#. But this particular method is mainly for compatibility when porting old VB code forward to .Net. New code, whether VB or C#, should use [Array.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) instead.